# Two different domain lists at AWS with iOS vs scratchpad

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ios7, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to use AWS SDK for iOS to access SimpleDB. When I use either the command-line tools or Javascript scratchpad provided at http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-SimpleDB they show me the domain I created. However, when I run the AWSiOSDemo sample, it doesn't list the domain. I tried using the code from AWSiOSDemo into my ios7 application, and it also does not list my domain, instead showing the domain that AWSiOSDemo sample created.

What is the reason for two different lists of domains? I am using the same authentication key etc for both methods, why am I getting two different views? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Amazon SimpleDB` supports 8 `regions and endpoints`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sdb_region

May be your `command line tool` & `Java-script scratchpad` both are showing the list of domain of default `region end point` i.e. `sdb.amazonaws.com`.  If you can set the `region end point` in your `AWSiOSDemo` sample than set the region `US East (Northern Virginia) Region`, it must list the domain you are looking for.

I can suggest you another solution. You can use `SDB Explorer`. `SDB Explorer` can show you all domains. `SDB Explorer` is free for 30 days. http://www.sdbexplorer.com/

Disclosure: I am one of the developer of SDB Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. Seems counter-intuitive that the regions are not replicating. I suggest the ldom commandline specify the region as well, when printing the domain information.